# How to define Generic interfaces with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following generic interface structure:

```
public interface IBase {}

public interface IBase<TBase> : IBase
  where TBase : class, IBase
{
   IEnumerable<IA<TBase>> Derived { get; }  
}

public interface IA {}

public interface IA<TBase> : IA
   where TBase : class, IBase
{
   IEnumerable<IB<TBase, IA<TBase>>> DerivedOfA { get; }
}

public interface IB {}

public interface IB<TBase, TA> : IB
   where TBase : class, IBase
   where TA : class, IA<TBase>
{
   IEnumerable<IC<TBase, TA, IB<TBase, TA>>> DerivedOfB { get; }
}

public interface IC {}

public interface IC<TBase, TA, TB> : IC
   where TBase : class, IBase
   where TA : class, IA<TBase>
   where TB : class, IB<TBase, TA>
{
}
```

The purpose of this interface structure is to define a contract of type objects in the heirarcy structure.

When I try to define the following:

```
public class Base : IBase
{
    public IEnumerable<IA<Base>> Derived { get; }

    public class DerivedA : IA<Base>
    {
        public IEnumerable<IB<Base , IA<Base>>> DerivedOfA { get; }

        public class DerivedB : IB<Base, DerivedA>
        {
              public IEnumerable<IC<Base, IA<Base>, IB<Base, IA<Base>>>> DerivedOfB { get; }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything compiles.

But when I define the 3rd nesting level (`IC`) compilation fails.

```
public class Base : IBase
{
    public IEnumerable<IA<Base>> Derived { get; }

    public class DerivedA : IA<Base>
    {
        public IEnumerable<IB<Base, IA<Base>>> DerivedOfA { get; }

        public class DerivedB : IB<Base, DerivedA>
        {
            public IEnumerable<IC<Base, IA<Base>, IB<Base, IA<Base>>>> DerivedOfB { get; }

            public class DerviedC: IC<Base, DerivedA, DerivedB>
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

(this creates a strict inheritance between the objects with the fact that the classes are nested).

When I write the code, the compiler complains on the following line

```
public class DerviedC: IC<Base, DerivedA, DerivedB>  <-----
```

with the following error message

```
Error   CS0311  The type 'Base.DerivedA.DerivedB' cannot be used as type parameter 'TB' in the 
generic type or method 'IC<TBase, TA, TB>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 
'Base.DerivedA.DerivedB' to 'IB<Base, Base.DerivedA>'.
```

It seems the 2nd inheritance level of the interfaces is not supported. Why?
As `Base.DerivedB` inherits `IB<Base, DerivedA>` I would assume the compiler will no how to up-cast the object to its reference.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: this doesnt compile since you have `IB<TBase>` and you have `IB<TBase, TA>` could you provide working example?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right approach? Using to many interfaces, and generic types can make the code difficult to understand and work with. What is the actual goal?

Comment: @Selvin: while I'm not sure to what you refer. I double checked the question and found I had a typo in `IB<TBase, TA>` interface definition. Can you review again?

Comment: @JonasH : enforce the inheritance in each level of the hierarchy. Layer if a polymorphic database holds objects at various levels, the derived types are enforced by the compiler.
Everything works as expected up until the `IC` interface level..

Comment: Obviously, things don't work as expected. Nested classes are rarely used and *never* for enforcing inheritance hierarchies - they have nothing to do with inheritance. I don't think I've ever seen 3 levels of nested classes in 20 years. Whatever you want to do, this is an overcomplicated way of doing it

Comment: Post an example that actually compiles and demonstrates the problem. There's no `IField` in the question. If people are forced to come up with their own types to reproduce the issue, they may end up with completely different results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Fixed (i am trying to emphasize the problem with a simplified version of the code. `IField` is the interface name in my code. so it is mainly a typo.
In addition I've posted a working examples... actually if I defined only up to level 2 of the nesting (`IB`), it works. it fails only on level 3 (`IC`)

Comment: this compiles fine on [.NET 6](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OBmgTm) but not on [4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eZSQK2) ... i've check locally and it compiles fine on 4.8